# Дефект в переводе "Норм Поведения" (часть про дружелюбие)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нормы-поведения

Оригинал (по ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation **makes it hard to be friendly**, **stop participating and move on**.

Текущий перевод (судя по всему основанный на более ранней версии документа, по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> Избегайте сарказма и будьте осторожны с шутками — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказываний. Если же обстоятельства **будят в вас гнев**, **не вступайте в разговор вовсе**.

В переводе фигурирует какой-то "гнев", которого нет в оригинале ни буквально, ни по смыслу. Также отличается концовка. Предлагаю исправить перевод на более корректный вариант:

> Избегайте сарказма и будьте осторожны с шутками — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказываний. Если же в обстоятельствах **вам трудно быть дружелюбным**, **прекратите участие в диалоге вовсе**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Формулировка заменена на:

> Избегайте сарказма и будьте осторожны с шутками — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказываний. Если же у вас не получается оставаться дружелюбным, прекратите разговор вовсе.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я не вижу в оригинале "makes you angry". В текущем переводе окрас совсем другой, отличный от оригинала.

Comment: @Suvitruf так предложите свой перевод!

Comment: Kromster уже предложил.

Comment: @Suvitruf я объяснил, чем он плох.

Comment: Но всё равно лучше того, что есть сейчас.

Comment: @Suvitruf ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Aer мне не кажется, что «Вам трудно быть дружелюбным» по-русски звучит подстегивающе в документе. При личном обращении - может быть, в зависимости от контекста. И наоборот, я не вижу в английской версии отсылки к - "Чувству сильного негодования или возмущения, **состояние крайнего раздражения или недовольства** кем-л., чем-л. (обычно бурно проявляющееся)"

Comment: "вам трудно оставаться" можно заменить на другую формулировку, к примеру "у вас не получается", или "вам не дают". Основная претензия к "гневу" и различиям в концовке.

Comment: @Kromster вот это уже лучше, давайте попробуем заменить.

Comment: А еще лучше согласовать концовку, т.к. сейчас есть несогласование - "Если **не получается** (в начале получалось, а потом перестало), **не вступайте** (даже не начинайте)". По идее, должно быть что-то типа "не получается - не продолжайте", или "не удается - прекратите"

Comment: @Kromster «Не получаться» может и по жизни... Хотя если вы настаиваете на передаче всех нюансов первоисточника, то да, надо перевести по-другому.

Answer (score 3):

Проблема текущего перевода в том, что окрас совсем другой. Если в оригинале подразумевается "спокойствие", акцент на то, что беседа слегка вызывает дискомфорт, то в текущем переводе акцент слишком сильный, будто беседа вас прям вынуждает рейджить.

Предложение Kromster'а, если там и есть огрехи, в любом случае лучше того, что сейчас. Да много вариантов так-то есть с тем же окрасом:

> Если же в текущих обстоятельствах вам трудно оставаться дружелюбным,
>   прекратите участие в диалоге вовсе.

Или:

> Если же в беседе вам трудно оставаться дружелюбным,
>   прекратите участие в диалоге вовсе.

Или:

> Если же в беседе вам трудно оставаться хладнокровным,
>   прекратите участие в диалоге вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

> If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

Еще один возможный вариант:

> Если вы считаете, что в сложившейся ситуации сложно оставаться дружелюбным, воздержитесь от участия, прервите диалог.

Из минусов, которые я вижу — «диалог». «Диалог» отдает «дискуссией», а SO не дискуссионный клуб.

Comment: Про "диалог", верно подмечено

Comment: @Kromster Подскажите, есть ли у вас мысли как улучшить?

Comment: ".. прекратите участие вовсе."

Comment: @Kromster звучит несколько иначе. Я воспринимаю это как «уйдите с сайта и более тут не появляйтесь», нежели «закройте эту вкладку и перейдите к следующему вопросу, если у вас осталось желание». Подскажите, есть ли у вас еще альтернативы?

Comment: в английском "хватит участвовать, и отпустите" тоже несколько раполагает к "выйдите с сайта и займитесь другими полезными делами"